# How to create a linear regression with R?

Tags: r

I have a simple **matrix** like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   11   12
```

I have to calculate a linear regression of these columns, like: `lm(x ~ y)`

Where thefirst column is the X, and the other are the Y? I mean... can I do something to use the other with **one** variable(y)

or

do i have to use something like: `lm(x~y+z+c+b)` etc etc ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but I wouldn't really recommend it:

```
> set.seed(2)
> mat <- matrix(runif(12), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> mat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.1848823 0.7023740 0.5733263
[2,] 0.1680519 0.9438393 0.9434750
[3,] 0.1291590 0.8334488 0.4680185
[4,] 0.5499837 0.5526741 0.2388948
> mod <- lm(mat[,1] ~ mat[,-1])
> mod

Call:
lm(formula = mat[, 1] ~ mat[, -1])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   mat[, -1]1   mat[, -1]2  
     1.0578      -1.1413       0.1177
```

Why is this not recommended? Well, you are abusing the formula interface here; it works but the model coefficients have odd names and you are incurring a lot of overhead of working with the formula interface, which is designed for extracting response/covariates from a data frame or list object referenced in the symbolic formula.

The usual way of working is:

```
df <- data.frame(mat)
names(df) <- c("Y","A","B")
## specify all terms:
lm(Y ~ A + B, data = df)
## or use the `.` shortcut
lm(Y ~ ., data = df)
```

If you don't want to go via the data frame, then you can call the workhorse function behind `lm()`, `lm.fit()`, directly with a simple manipulation:

```
lm.fit(cbind(rep(1, nrow(mat)), mat[,-1]), mat[, 1])
```

here we bind on a vector of 1s to columns 2 and 3 of `mat` (`cbind(rep(1, nrow(mat)), mat[,-1])`); this is the model matrix. `mat[, 1]` is the response. Whilst it doesn't return an `"lm"` classed object, it will be very quick and can relatively easily be converted to one if that matters.

By the way, you have the usual notation back to front. Y is usually the response, with X indicating the covariates used to model or predict Y.

Comment: @Dail `lm()` is a high-level interface to lower-level code. Most of the guts of `lm()` is in processing a formula to build the model matrix and extract the response. In your case, you almost have the model matrix and the response and a simple manipulation gets the full model matrix (see my updated Answer), so in calling `lm()` with a matrix you are calling largely redundant code when you could call `lm.fit()` directly. Depends on what you want to do with the model fit once you have it.